# How to create a validation rule to prevent negative numbers?

Tags: validation, cakephp-2.0, models, rules

I'm using Cakephp 2.5.4

I want to validate the input of a field in a table so that negative numbers can not be entered.
I know what can be done with JavaScript, but for learning purposes, I would like to achieve a validation function and then apply it as a rule in the model.
For example, I have a table named species with a field called price. Within the model Species I have:

```
var $validate = array(

        'precio_kg' => array(

            'notEmpty' => array(

                    'rule' => 'notEmpty',

                    'message' => 'Este campo no puede ser vacío'

                       ),

            'checkPositivo' => array(

                    'rule' => array('checkPositivo'),

                    'message'=>'The value can not be negative'

                            )

                    )

                       );
```

Any idea how to write within that model the function for such a rule?

From already thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can [add your own validation methods](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods) to models.

```
'rule' => array('checkPositive'), // in the validation array

public function checkPositive($check) {
    return bccomp($check['precio_kg'], 0);
}
```

You can tweak this if you want to allow zero.

[bccomp docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Core validation methods, including Natural Numbers:

```
public $validate = array(
    'precio_kg' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Este campo no puede estar vacío.'
        ),
        'checkPositivo' => array(
            'rule' => 'naturalNumber',
            'message' => 'Este número no puede ser negativo.'
        )
    )
);
```